# Cannot see File Explorer and Project Explorer side panel in Drools 6?

Tags: drools, workbench, drools-guvnor

I'm new to drools and using Drools 6.2. While following some tutorials I found that I'm missing File Explorer and Project Explorer from my drools workbench (old guvnor) . Which basically makes it useless. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution (File Explorer):**
This issue was caused because I was using chrome. After trying for a whole day I found the simple solution to use Firefox. I got my File Explorer working now, but the Project Explorer was still not visible.

**Solution (Project Explorer):**
I found that this is a known issue in Drools (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-666) and that there are two fixes for this :

**Solution 1:** 
Somehow, the Project Authoring link in the menu led to "...KIEWepapp.html?org.kie.guvnor.Problems". After realizing that, I just entered the correct URL ending on "org.kie.guvnor.explorer" in the browser and got the expected screen including the project explorer on the right side of the window. Since then, the Project Authoring link in the menu works as expected.

So from my homepage 
http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7/kie-drools-wb.html#org.kie.workbench.common.screens.home.client.HomePresenter

I manually browsed to the url : http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7/kie-drools-wb.html#org.kie.guvnor.explorer

**Solution 2**:
Was to nuke the layout. Click no the top right corner of app with icon having a ‘+’ symbol (indicates a medical kit). This will ask you to reset the layout. Accept it and you’ll see the Project explorer.

[image: Reset Layout]